# Android: BatteryLevel widget not updating

Tags: android, service, android-widget

I'm having some problems using RemoteViews. Simply want to make a widget that shows battery level. I've done all other stuffs already.

Here is my class:

```
public class BatteryLevel extends AppWidgetProvider{

    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ){
        context.startService(new Intent(context, BatteryMonitorReceiver.class));
    }

    public static class BatteryMonitorReceiver extends Service{
        private int currentBatteryLevel = 0;

        private BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ){
                currentBatteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra( "level", 0 );
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onStart (Intent intent, int startId) {          
            registerReceiver( this.batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter( Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED ) );
            RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews( getPackageName(), R.layout.main );
            updateViews.setTextViewText( R.id.level, String.valueOf(currentBatteryLevel));

            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName( this, BatteryLevel.class );
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance( this );
            manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When i start the app no error and btw no update at R.id.level.

What's wrong?

Note: api version 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your service is an inner class, I guess you have not declared it in your Android Manifest, which is needed.
And you shouldn't use `onStart`, it is deprecated. Use `onStartCommand`. And you forgot to unregister your receiver...

Comment: Thx for answer. But still got problems. Updated manifest and changed onStart to onStartCommand but does not override now.

Comment: The parameters are different. Read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html